# If crontab executes at midnight, what will the current date be?

Tags: cron, time

I have the following entry in cron:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

in `script.sh`, there's a call to:

```
date +%Y%m%d
```

Even if this executed in zero-time, I'm assuming that the value of date will be for the date after midnight, rather than the date before. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct once the clock hits 00:00:00 date = date +1

However, if you really wanted it to be the day before you could do this in your date command:

`date "yesterday" +%Y%m%d`

Comment: OK. The script in question moves the current apache log to a file named with that date, then gzip's it. Would make more sense, therefore, for it to use yesterday's date since *most* of the requests will be from that date.

Comment: @Bobby: Look at logrotate instead of rolling your own: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Computers view 00:00.00 as the start of a new day, so it will be for the date after midnight, not the date before.